# How to post images on my blog with a pre-defined border

Tags: images

The images in this blog post: http://wordfruit.com/blog/the-hole-through-the-earth-3/

...have borders around them -- hatched lines.

But in this post: http://wordfruit.com/blog/copywriting-for-fish/ there's no border around the image.

The images in the first example above I think I posted using the 'From url' function.

In the second example listed, I used the 'upload' function when posting the image.

Is there a way of posting images using the 'upload' function so that the border appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more a css problem than wordpress related -

check style.css of your theme: the 'border' (actually a padding with background image) is only set for left, right, and center aligned images (like those from your first link), not for those with .alignnone (those from your second link):

```
#content img.alignleft, 
#content img.alignright, 
#content img.aligncenter {
    background:url("images/wf-hashes-wht.gif") repeat scroll center center transparent;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    padding:6px;
}
```

if you want the same behaviour for non-aligned images, add `#content img.alignnone` to the above list (don't forget to add the comma)